# Removed state and country from estimate shipping

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-tax

I have removed region id from estimate shipping based on [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601634/magento-controller-to-ajax-estimate-shipping-load-block-and-display-phtml)

It seems that after this change I can't see/get taxes for a region. If I set the tax rule for USA and all regions then I can see tax field. If I set the same rule to be for a specific region then I am not able too see taxes.

Can someone give me an idea how to fix this?

Comment: In order to display taxes, region is required. Even if I managed to see shipping rates based on zip I can't see taxes. Is there any way I find the region based on zipcode? I have tax rules only for 2 states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: I hide the state which was already set as default US and also hide Region - which I calculate and update in dropdown based on zip code. So, even if the user can't see those fields, they are in the page and the estimate works as expected.

Comment: What I used to get region based on zip : [link](http://bassistance.de/2009/03/03/jquery-snippet-autocomplete-city-based-on-zip-code/)
Does anyone know any issue with this solution?